# Stale element exception handling is not working in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

The following code cannot handle the Stale element exception error:

```
        website_accessable = False
        try:
            driver.get(addressToVerify)
            website_accessable = True
        except WebDriverException as e:
            if 'net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR' in str(e):
                print("--- Error: SSL error protocol occurred!")
                return website_accessable
        except TimeoutException:
            print("--- Error: Webpage openning Time out!")
            return website_accessable
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            print("--- Error: Stale element referenced!")
            return website_accessable               
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error:", str(e))
            return website_accessable
```

and full error is shown in the console (Second exception fired).
Any ideas?

Full Error:

```
Message: stale element reference: stale element not found
  (Session info: chrome=119.0.6045.123); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#stale-element-reference-exception
Stacktrace:
0   chromedriver                        0x0000000101d90d28 chromedriver + 4795688
1   chromedriver                        0x0000000101d882b3 chromedriver + 4760243
2   chromedriver                        0x000000010196188d chromedriver + 407693
3   chromedriver                        0x0000000101967d6f chromedriver + 433519
4   chromedriver                        0x000000010196a0c4 chromedriver + 442564
5   chromedriver                        0x000000010196a20c chromedriver + 442892
6   chromedriver                        0x00000001019a9fa2 chromedriver + 704418
7   chromedriver                        0x00000001019d7ca2 chromedriver + 892066
8   chromedriver                        0x00000001019a3c63                       0x00000001019d7a73
```

Comment: Show the full error traceback, and also show in your code where `StaleElementReferenceException` is defined/imported.

Comment: Also, I don't see how `driver.get()` could even raise that exception.  Are you sure this code is where the error happens?

Comment: That error traceback did not come from this code.  The stale element exception is happening elsewhere in your code.

Comment: @JohnGordon it could not come from somewhere else, because I just have one place to open a webpage as I mentioned in the question

Comment: "Opening a webpage" cannot cause a stale element exception, as far as I know.  So the error must be happening elsewhere.

Comment: And where did that error message come from?  That is not a standard Python exception message.  Are you sure that is the **whole** stack trace?

Comment: "Second exception fired" No it did not, else we would have seen the `print()` message output.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thank you! you were completely correct. The error was from another part of the code.